# Several JkUnmount(s) in multiple VirutalHost(s)

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk, tomcat7

I am trying to configure multiple VirtualHosts in my mod_jk.conf.

I have a few JKMounts and several JKUnmounts which will be common to all of the VirtualHosts. I was trying to move these *mounts to JKMountFile. After a while, I realized that the syntax of mounts that I was using in JKMountFile was incorrect and that it does not support JKUnmount.

Is there a JKUnmountFile equivalent or an alternative to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do is to put a **!** before the rule and it is treated as an unMount. More here : http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html